# Displaying a float to a number of decimals

Tags: iphone, xcode, variables, formatting

Seems an easy question. And it can be done using the following format "%.#f". Replacing # with a number will give you that number of decimals.
But what if you want to pass in an NSInteger variable to specify the value of #?

I am trying to display a label containing a price with the number of decimals the user had previously specified. Is this possible?

The following code is what a want to change.
I want to substitute the hardcoded number (in this case "4") with a variable of type NSInteger.

```
lblPrice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f",val_stdPrice];
```

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct the formatting string dynamically:

```
NSString *fmtString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%.%df", 17];
NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:fmtString, 1.337f];
NSLog (resultString);
```

Comment: So simple. How didn't i think of that? A bad day at the office rescued by your kind self. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the Integer and append it to the string to match the format. 
Then use the string as a parameter.

Comment: Would i do that using "%.%df"? I'm a total newbie so i may need to see a line of code to understand what you mean. I have added some more description to the original question. Thanks

Comment: See my solution Ollie - 17 being your 4 :D